# How to iterate over JSON returned by HttpClient

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a simple Angular HttpClient, which is correctly returning JSON. I am attempting to cast the results to enforce type safety (not sure if this is correct).

But how do I actually access the returned JSON to copy it into an array?

The httpClient get() request is (and seems to be working fine):

```
public sendGetRequest(): Observable<Symbols[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Symbols[]>(this.REST_API_SERVER);
  }
```

The Symbols interface is

```
export interface Symbols {
  code: string
  desc: string
}
```

I have a component which calls the data service and is getting a response.  However the code below returns an error when attempting to map the JSON into a string array

```
ERROR TypeError: syms.map is not a function
```

```
listOfOption: Array<{ value: string; label: string }> = []

this.dataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe((syms: Symbols[]) => {
  console.log('return value ' + JSON.stringify(syms))
  // console output shows the returned JSON and it looks correct

  //this does not work, how do I copy the results to a string array??
  this.listOfOption = syms.map(results => {
     return {
        value: results.code,
        label: results.code,
     }
  })
})
```

The JSON data structure is:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "code": "code1",
      "desc": "Long description of code 1"
    },
    {
      "code": "code2",
      "desc": "Long description of code 2"
    },
    {
      "code": "code3",
      "desc": "Long description of code 3"
    },
    {
      "code": "code4",
      "desc": "Long description of code 4"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is driving me crazy

Comment: it shoud be `syms.results.map`.

Comment: This won't compile, error is Property 'result' does not exist on type 'Symbols[]'

Comment: `subscribe((syms: Symbols[])` instead this try `subscribe(syms: any)` and then try `syms.results.map`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. However I'm wondering what that does to the type safety of the return value? Is there any point in casting the results to an interface?

Comment: Also I'm not sure how to flag your comment as the correct answer

Comment: You could also change it to `subscribe((syms: {results: Symbols[]}) => ...` to keep the type information

Comment: Thanks Jon, what would the function definition of sendGetRequest() need to be to support that return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model a new interface called responseData to support response type.

```
export interface responseData{
  results: Symbols[]
}


export interface Symbols {
   code: string
   desc: string
}
```

Update the same in service

```
public sendGetRequest(): Observable<responseData> {
  return this.httpClient.get<responseData>(this.REST_API_SERVER);
}
```

You can now retrieve the results using array.map()

```
listOfOption: Array<{ value: string; label: string }> = []

this.dataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe((syms: responseData) => {
  console.log('return value ' + syms)

  
  this.listOfOption = syms.results.map(result => {
     return {
        value: result.code,
        label: result.code,
     }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the most complete answer and maintains the type safety.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

The response data has an `object` root, but you're trying to parse it as an `array` root. I think the simplest solution would be something like this:

```js
public sendGetRequest(): Observable<Symbols[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<{results: Symbols[]}>(this.REST_API_SERVER)
    .pipe(pluck('results'));
}
```

Which specifies that the response data is an object with a field named `results` which holds an array of `Symbols`.

Alternatively you could also extract the response type to a separate definition:

```js
interface ApiResponse {
  results: Symbols[]
}

public sendGetRequest(): Observable<Symbols[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<ApiResponse>(this.REST_API_SERVER)
    .pipe(pluck('results'));
}
```

Comment: This will cause a type mismatch error unless you use a `map`  operator to pick the results part.

Comment: Right you are! Updated my answer

Comment: Not having much luck with those suggestions. Both will not  compile due to erro Property 'pluck' does not exist on type 'Observable<{ results: Symbols[];

Comment: And second suggestion error is Property 'pluck' does not exist on type 'Observable<ApiResponse>'

Comment: Ah sorry. I thought Angular used the full operator set from RxJS. I've changed the code to use `map` instead

Comment: Still no luck, now the error is Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<ApiResponse>'

Comment: I forgot they changed this in RxJS 6(?). Need to put `pipe` in there. I've updated my answer

Comment: @JonGStødle if you change `public sendGetRequest(): Observable<{results: Symbols[]}> ` this should work too. hence the type safty is protected too